# C# - why does closing NetworkStream disconnect TcpClient?

Tags: c#, .net, tcpclient

In `C#`, if I close a `NetworkStream` that was instantiated from `TCPClient.GetStream()`, it disconnects my TCP client.

Take this code for example:

```
TcpClient tcpClient = new();
IPEndPoint ipEndPoint = new(IPAddress.Parse("xxx.xxx.xx.xx"), 1026);
tcpClient.Connect(ipEndPoint);

Console.WriteLine($"Before open stream: tcpClient.Connected == {tcpClient.Connected}");

NetworkStream stream = tcpClient.GetStream();
Console.WriteLine($"After get stream: tcpClient.Connected == {tcpClient.Connected}");

stream.Close();
Console.WriteLine($"After close stream: tcpClient.Connected == {tcpClient.Connected}");

tcpClient.Close();
```

The above code gives me this result:

```
Before open stream: tcpClient.Connected == True
After get stream: tcpClient.Connected == True
After close stream: tcpClient.Connected == False
```

Could someone explain to me why this happens? Or maybe explain (for dummies) how `TcpClient` and its `NetworkStream` are related such that this *should* work this way?

Comment: Why _shouldnt_ it?

Comment: @Dai Given that the `NetworkStream` object is not required for `TcpClient` to be connected, it seems that getting and closing the `NetworkStream` shouldn't have any bearing on the state of the `TcpClient`.. Different object. I can't make sense of it.

Comment: By closing/disposing the network stream you indicate that you are no longer interested in reading or writing from the socket.  Nothing left to be done with it, so the socket gets disposed.

Comment: @ARC `TcpClient` doesn't "implement `NetworkStream`", it just wraps it (and you can use `NetworkStream` without using `TcpClient` too) - and `NetworkStream` itself is an Adapter Pattern wrapper to (imperfectly) adapt a `Socket` to a `System.IO.Stream`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think, it is because it is reasonable to close the entire connection once the stream is closed. When we take a look into the source code of TcpClient we can see the following implementation:

https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System/net/System/Net/Sockets/TCPClient.cs

```
    public NetworkStream GetStream() {
        if(Logging.On)Logging.Enter(Logging.Sockets, this, "GetStream", "");
        if (m_CleanedUp){
            throw new ObjectDisposedException(this.GetType().FullName);
        }
        if (!Client.Connected) {
            throw new InvalidOperationException(SR.GetString(SR.net_notconnected));
        }
        if (m_DataStream==null) {
            m_DataStream = new NetworkStream(Client, true);
        }
        if(Logging.On)Logging.Exit(Logging.Sockets, this, "GetStream", m_DataStream);
        return m_DataStream;
    }
```

It says `new NetworkStream(Client, true)`.

According to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.networkstream.-ctor?view=net-6.0#system-net-sockets-networkstream-ctor(system-net-sockets-socket-system-boolean) the second argument is `ownsSocket`.

Under Remarks, the following is stated:

*If the value of ownsSocket parameter is true, the NetworkStream takes ownership of the underlying Socket, and calling the Close method also closes the underlying Socket.*

So closing the underlying socket means, that the connection is closed, and therefore `TcpClient.Connected` is `false`.

Comment: Also note that `GetStream()` doesn't create a new `NetworkStream` instance, it returns the one-and-only `NetworkStream` for this `TcpClient` object.  The fact that the one-and-only stream is instantiated inside `GetStream()` is just an optimization (lazy evaluation) and shouldn't be considered when analyzing object lifetime.